# Multiple functions on two click on same element

Tags: javascript

I want to run two different functions on click of an element. If I click a button first time clickfunction1 should run and when I click the button second time clickfunction2 should run. My problem is when I click an element on alternate basis two different functions should run one by one, like on first click first function will run and on clicking second time the same element second function will run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Navigation Focus/Blur</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<style>
.imageclick {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

a {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 33px 15px 33px;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 3px;
}

 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

a {
    background-color: #23527c;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}



.clickbox {
    margin: 20px 0;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    background-color: #9ecbf3;
    display: none;

}

.icon-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
}

button {
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("navigate").style.display = "block";
    }

    function clickFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("navigate").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="text-center">Navigation Focus/Blur</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 imageclick">
                    <button onclick="clickFunction1()" onclick="clickFunction2()">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
                    </button>

                     <div class="clickbox" id="navigate">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                        <a href="#">Serve</a>
                        <a href="#">Webst</a>
                        <a href="#">Graph</a>
                        <a href="#">SeoD</a>
                        <a href="#">CPhp</a>
                        <a href="#">Wpres</a>
                        <a href="#">PlC++</a>
                        <a href="#">Pjava</a>
                        <a href="#">Angjs</a>
                        <a href="#">JavaS</a>
                        <a href="#">PPyth</a>
                        <a href="#">Photo</a>
                        <a href="#">ILLust</a>
                        <a href="#">CoraL</a>
                        <a href="#">PHtml</a>
                        <a href="#">Lcss3</a>
                        <a href="#">Lbstrp</a>
                        <a href="#">Jquery</a>
                     </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `button onclick="clickFunction1()" onclick="clickFunction2()"` weird! why dont you write a logic to find the click count and handle it

Comment: What should happen on a third click?

Answer (score 1):

In this solution I create a new function clickFunction() with no number, to manage your two existing functions and I also declare a boolean flag which I toggle...

```
    var Toggle=false;

    function clickFunction(Toggle2){

    if(Toggle2){clickFunction1();} else {clickFunction2();}

    Toggle=!Toggle;

   }
```

The basic HTML...

```
<button onclick="clickFunction(Toggle);"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to achieve, there is no need of 2 functions. You can just read the current display and toggle the value.

```
function clickFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById("navigate");
  const display = element.style.display || 'block' /* default style if inline display doesnt exist on load */;
  element.style.display = display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function with a counter. When the click is odd(first click) the first function will be called else the second will be called

```js
var count=0;
function decide()
{
count++;
if(count%2==1)
clickFunction1();
else
clickFunction2();
}


function clickFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("navigate").style.display = "block";
}

function clickFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("navigate").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.imageclick {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

a {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 33px 15px 33px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 3px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  background-color: #23527c;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.clickbox {
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-color: #9ecbf3;
  display: none;
}

.icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

button {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Navigation Focus/Blur</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h2 class="text-center">Navigation Focus/Blur</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 imageclick">
          <button onclick="decide()">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
                    </button>

          <div class="clickbox" id="navigate">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Serve</a>
            <a href="#">Webst</a>
            <a href="#">Graph</a>
            <a href="#">SeoD</a>
            <a href="#">CPhp</a>
            <a href="#">Wpres</a>
            <a href="#">PlC++</a>
            <a href="#">Pjava</a>
            <a href="#">Angjs</a>
            <a href="#">JavaS</a>
            <a href="#">PPyth</a>
            <a href="#">Photo</a>
            <a href="#">ILLust</a>
            <a href="#">CoraL</a>
            <a href="#">PHtml</a>
            <a href="#">Lcss3</a>
            <a href="#">Lbstrp</a>
            <a href="#">Jquery</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically register click event on element you want, and then unregister it to control what function will be call when user clicking it.

For your specific case, you should first register the `clickFunction1` first, and inside it, you unregister itself and then register the `clickFunction2`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.querySelector('button')  // Replace `button` with your selector

btn.addEventListener('click', clickFunction1)

function clickFunction1() {
  document.getElementById('navigate').style.display = 'block'

  // make clicking the button call other function
  btn.removeEventListener('click', clickFunction1)
  btn.addEventListener('click', clickFunction2)
}

function clickFunction2() {
  document.getElementById('navigate').style.display = 'none'
}
</script>
```